# Nested form object fields not displayed

Tags: ruby, padrino

I'm using Padrino and trying to display an image upload field inside a form of an object that has many images.
Model **project.rb**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, class_name: 'ProjectImage', foreign_key: 'project_id'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Model **project_image.rb**

```
class ProjectImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  mount_uploader :file, ProjectUploader
end
```

Controller **projects.rb**

```
get :new do
  @title = pat(:new_title, :model => 'project')
  @project = Project.new
  @project.images.build
  render 'projects/new'
end
```

Partial **projects/_form.haml**

```
= form_for :project, url(:projects, :create), multipart: true, :class => 'form-horizontal' do |f|
  - f.fields_for :images do |image_f|
    =image_f.label :file, :class => 'control-label'
    .controls
      =image_f.file_field :file, :class => 'form-control input-xlarge input-with-feedback', :multiple => true
```

But nested `image_f` fields are not displayed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
= form_for :project, url(:projects, :create), multipart: true, :class => 'form-horizontal' do |f|
```

to

```
= form_for @project, url(:projects, :create), multipart: true, :class => 'form-horizontal' do |f|
```

Most likely you will also need to change `- f.fields_for` to `= f.fields_for`

Comment: Changing `- f.fields_for` to `= f.fields_for` did it while `:project` to `@project` had no effect. Thanks!